# DataGridView generate column for property with browsable false

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource

Either I am doing something wrong or this is a bug.

I have an interface `IPerson` which has one property set to `[Browsable(false)]`.
After I created a new `UserControl` (*UC*), dragged a `DataGridView`(*DGV*) into it and generated a `BindingSource` (*BS*) for the interface and assigned it to the DGV it renders totally fine and the property does **not** show up.
In the constructor of the UC i created a sample `Person` and assigned it as the source of the BS, just so i have at least a row in the DGV to look at.

I created a `Form` and dragged the new created UC onto it just to see that the evil property shows up as a Column.

**WHY?**

I tried a few things, from recompiling, to casting the concrete class to the interface but i still have the same issue. On the Form the Control suddenly creates a column for it, while the Control it self does a) not have it b) does not create it either.

```
 // person interface
 public interface IPerson : IEntity
 {
    string Surname { get; set; }
    int Age { get; }

    [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    Gender Gender { get; set; }
    Address Address { get; set; }

    //THIS IS THE BAD BED :-P which should not show up
    [DefaultValue(null), Browsable(false), ReadOnly(true)]
    IBed Bed { get; set; }
 }

// this is the UserCOntrol with a DGV in it, it displays it fine...
// and does not generate the column for the property
public partial class PersonControlView : UserControl
{
    public PersonControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // just a temporary test ...
        var l = new List<IPerson>
        {
            new Person
            {
                Address =
                    new Address
                    {
                        City = "Cologne",
                        Country = "Germany",
                        County = "***",
                        Number = "**",
                        Postcode = "*****",
                        Street = "**** Strasse"
                    },
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1886, 32, 13),
                Gender = Gender.Male,
                Name = "***",
                Surname = "***"
            }
        };

        set(l);
    }
    // just a temporary test method...
    public void set(IList<IPerson> persons)
    {
        iPersonBindingSource.DataSource = persons;
    }
```

Some pictures

This is the view on the UserControl, it generated the columns correctly as shown on the picture
[image: This is how it looks on the UserControl]

This is the control after i drag it from the toolbox onto the form ... the population happens in the constructor (see the test code above). The field should not be displayed - correct?
[image: This is how it looks on the Form]

Answer (score 0):

**Facepalm** OK, following happened:

I created the control and the DGV before I set the attribute on the property. This caused to actually create the column for the property.

Then I added the attribute to the propert, refreshed the datasource and the DGV in the control must have switched the column to visible=false.

*So the column was always there, just didnt display in the UserControl*
*The question is, why did it suddenly in the form?* (*)

(*) irrelevant since i fixed my problem. but still mysterious behaviour

I removed the DGV again from the control (which removed obviously all columns as well, re-created it, assigned the DataSource and now it behaves as expected.